# How to make a button on startScene go to GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am looking to make a button that brings me from my startScene to my GameScene. Everything I find is to have the transition happen when I click the screen, not the button. This is what I found but isn't working. Thoughts?

```
    var startButton = SKNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    startButton = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 50))
    startButton.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(startButton)

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    let gameSceneTransition = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")        
    let touch = touches
    let location = touch.first!.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    // If next button is touched, start transition to second scene
    if (node.name == "startButton") {
        self.scene?.view?.presentScene(gameSceneTransition!, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare the name of the node you need to set the name property of the node. Simply saying:

```
var startButton = SKNode()
```

Does not set the node's name property. You most also say

```
startButton.name = "startButton"
```

You could just say

```
if node == startButton
{
    self.scene?.view?.presentScene(gameSceneTransition!, transition: SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1.0))
}
```